# Error while building Dokan mirror.c using VS2013

Tags: dll

I have downloaded the Dokan Library 0.6.0 (used to make a file system). I'm using VS 2013 and have created a project to build the sample called mirror.c. It uses a DLL called Dokan.dll. I have properly named the Dokan library which is dokan.lib. It compiles just fine but the linker gives an error saying "unresolved external symbol _DokanMain@8 referenced in function _wmain".

I suspect that DokanMain is in Dokan.dll so I added a statement as follows:
    extern __declspec(dllimport) int DOKANAPI
      DokanMain(
      PDOKAN_OPTIONS    DokanOptions,
      PDOKAN_OPERATIONS DokanOperations);

But that leads to two more errors:
    warning C4141: 'dllexport' : used more than once
    'DokanMain' : inconsistent dll linkage

I have never used a dll before so maybe there is something else I need to do. Perhaps in the project properties? Of mybe the syntax above is incorrect.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you changing the name of the dll?  This seems more of a Stackoverflow question to be honest.

Comment: I didn't change the name of the dll. What I meant to say was I properly named the dll in the properties of the Visual Studio project. i.e., I entered ../doken.lib.

Comment: Like I said this seems like more of a Stackoverflow question because of the compiler error.

Comment: Thanks, based on your first suggestion I have asked on Stackoverflow.